# Callbackquery handler issue in python telegram bot

Tags: python, python-telegram-bot

In my code I'm facing an issue with `callbackquery` handler, when I'm hit `/start` command **Next** button appear and when I'm hitting on that button it gives me reply as **hi**, till this output is correct. Then when I'm hitting another command `/help` then **help** button appears, when I hit that **help** button then it gives me same reply for next button is **hi**.

***Conclusion:*** Is there is way to kill old `callbackquery` handler. I found way is return `Conversationhandler.END` from `callbackquery` handler function but it limits my functionality had googled for it but no found expected output.

**Here is my code:**

```
 from telegram import InlineKeyboardButton, InlineKeyboardMarkup
 from telegram.ext import Updater, CommandHandler, CallbackQueryHandler, ConversationHandler

 TELEGRAM_HTTP_API_TOKEN = 'token'

 FIRST, SECOND, HELP = range(3)

 def start(bot, update):
        keyboard = [
            [InlineKeyboardButton(u"Next", callback_data=str(FIRST))]
        ]
        reply_markup = InlineKeyboardMarkup(keyboard)
        update.message.reply_text(
            u"Start handler, Press next",
            reply_markup=reply_markup
        )
        return FIRST

 def first(bot, update):
        query = update.callback_query
        #reply_markup = InlineKeyboardMarkup(keyboard)
        bot.send_message(chat_id=query.message.chat_id,
                         text='hi')

 def help(bot,update):
        keyboard = [
            [InlineKeyboardButton(u"HELP", callback_data=str(HELP))]
        ]
        reply_markup = InlineKeyboardMarkup(keyboard)
        update.message.reply_text(
            u"Help handler, Press button",
            reply_markup=reply_markup
        )

        return HELP

 def myhelp(bot,update):
        query = update.callback_query
        bot.send_message(chat_id=query.message.chat_id,
                         text='help')

 updater = Updater(TELEGRAM_HTTP_API_TOKEN)

 conv_handler = ConversationHandler(
        entry_points=[CommandHandler('start', start)],
        states={
            FIRST: [CallbackQueryHandler(first)]
        },
        fallbacks=[CommandHandler('start', start)]
    )
 conv_handler1=ConversationHandler(
        entry_points=[CommandHandler('help',help)],
        states={
            HELP: [CallbackQueryHandler(myhelp)]
        },
        fallbacks=[CommandHandler('help',help)]
    )

 updater.dispatcher.add_handler(conv_handler)
 updater.dispatcher.add_handler(conv_handler1)

 updater.start_polling()

 updater.idle()
```

[This is code screenshot output for more detail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i53DP.png)

Any kind of help is welcome.

Answer (score 0):

You need to [make your bot persistent](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/wiki/Making-your-bot-persistent) (so state don't get lost), [add error handler](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/wiki/Exception-Handling) (to know if something failed) and fallback route (if there is not route matching).

In that case you'll know what's going wrong and where.